# Can I safely sell a used keyboard without risk of new owner recovering previous inputs?

Tags: forensics, physical, keyboard

As far as of my knowledge goes, keyboard don't store keystrokes in their memory by default (excluding those bundled with keyloggers). The thing that comes to my mind though is that some keyboards do have some built-in memory for storing user's preferences (e.g. gaming keyboards). Can this be somehow reprogrammed to store other data than just LEDs color combo?

**Can I sell my keyboard without worrying that new owner might recover previous input in some way?**

Cheers,
Dominic

Comment: They could look at which keys got the most wear and maybe make some guesses about your activities from that, and maybe do analysis on any dust the find, but your passwords are safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can this be somehow reprogrammed to store other data than just LEDs color combo?

Yes. Anything that have writable memory and a processor can be programmed. Will it be reprogrammed? I seriously doubt.

> Can I sell my keyboard without worrying that new owner might recover previous input in some way?

You can sell it, no worries. You haven't exported the firmware, reverse-engineered it, reprogrammed it and changed it to record everything, so there's no previous input saved anywhere.